# Idris Vect.fromList usage with generated list

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I am trying to feel my way into dependent types. Based on the logic of the **windowl** function below, I want to return a list of vectors whose length depend on the **size** provided.

```
window : (n : Nat) -> List a -> List (Vect n a)
window size = map fromList loop
  where
    loop xs = case splitAt size xs of
      (ys, []) => if length ys == size then [ys] else []
      (ys, _) => ys :: loop (drop 1 xs)

windowl : Nat -> List a -> List (List a)
windowl size = loop
  where
    loop xs = case List.splitAt size xs of
      (ys, []) => if length ys == size then [ys] else []
      (ys, _) => ys :: loop (drop 1 xs)
```

When I attempt to load the function into Idris, I get the following:

```
When checking argument func to function Prelude.Functor.map:
    Type mismatch between
            (l : List elem) -> Vect (length l) elem (Type of fromList)
    and
            a1 -> List (Vect size a) (Expected type)
    
    Specifically:
            Type mismatch between
                    Vect (length v0) elem
            and
                    List (Vect size a)
```

When reading the documentation on [fromList](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/base_doc/docs/Data.Vect.html#fromList) I notice that it says

> The length of the list should be statically known.

So I assume that the type error has to do with Idris not knowing that the length of the list is corresponding to the size specified.

I am stuck because I don't even know if it is something impossible I want to do or whether I can specify that the length of the list corresponds to the length of the vector that I want to produce.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: An simple way of writing the `window` function is [here](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/4394f3edf07a9ccc930e454491a2e257). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since in your case it is not possible to know the length statically, we need a function which can fail at run-time:

```
total
fromListOfLength : (n : Nat) -> (xs : List a) -> Maybe (Vect n a)
fromListOfLength n xs with (decEq (length xs) n)
  fromListOfLength n xs | (Yes prf) = rewrite (sym prf) in Just (fromList xs)
  fromListOfLength n xs | (No _) = Nothing
```

`fromListOfLength` converts a list of length `n` into a vector of length `n` or fails. Now let's combine it and `windowl` to get to `window`.

```
total
window : (n : Nat) -> List a -> List (Vect n a)
window n = catMaybes . map (fromListOfLength n) . windowl n
```

Observe that the `window` function's type is still an underspecification of what we are doing with the input list, because nothing prevents us from always returning the empty list (this could happen if `fromListOfLength` returned `Nothing` all the time).