# How to generate a Decidable inequality proof in Idris2?

Tags: idris, idris2

I know that `Decidable.Equality` has `decDeq` to be used for generating proofs about equality. For example, from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44079181/4196578), one can use `decEq` to decide if the length of a List is equal to the length of a target Vect, and then convert the List to Vect if the lengths are equal (code copied below).

I am trying to extend this and generate inequality proof. Given a List, I wanted to take the first `n` elements, provided that its number of elements is *greater than or equal to* `n`.

The original code with decEq is:

```
import Decidable.Equality
total
fromListOfLength : (n : Nat) -> (xs : List a) -> Maybe (Vect n a)
fromListOfLength n xs with (decEq (length xs) n)
  fromListOfLength n xs | (Yes prf) = rewrite (sym prf) in Just (fromList xs)
  fromListOfLength n xs | (No _) = Nothing
```

I tried (unsuccessfully) to adapt this to inequalities as follows:

```
import Decidable.Decidable
total
fromListLenGE : (n : Nat) -> (xs : List a) -> Maybe (Vect n a)
fromListLenGE n xs with (decide LTE (length xs) n)
  fromListLenGE n xs | (Yes prf) = ?xxx
  fromListLenGE n xs | (No _) = Nothing
```

I couldn't figure out how to use the `decide` method to generate the inequality proof. This is for learning purposes.

*Could someone help explain how to generate the LTE proof here so as to take the first `n` elements?*